# mongoose connection throwing MongooseServerSelectionError

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, timeout, mongoose-schema, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to my mongodb Atlas via the mongoose driver and it keeps throwing a *`MongooseServerSelectionError`*, 
and i have checked my username and password for the database user and it is correct.

Here is my code:

```
server running on port 3000
we are connected: { MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (/home/ateyib/UCSD-classes/CSE 135/hw3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/ateyib/UCSD-classes/CSE 135/hw3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:808:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/ateyib/UCSD-classes/CSE 135/hw3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ateyib/UCSD-classes/CSE 135/hw3/server.js:17:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:738:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
  message: 'connection timed out',
  name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
  reason:
   TopologyDescription {
     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
     setName: 'Cluster0-shard-0',
     maxSetVersion: null,
     maxElectionId: null,
     servers:
      Map {
        'cluster0-shard-00-00-ebets.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
        'cluster0-shard-00-01-ebets.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
        'cluster0-shard-00-02-ebets.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
     stale: false,
     compatible: true,
     compatibilityError: null,
     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     commonWireVersion: 8 },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is something related to your ip address probably.
Go to `Network Access` toolbar option click on EDIT button and then on ADD CURRENT IP ADDRESS and confirm.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Mongo 3.6 and Mongoose 5.9.1 connecting to a replicaSet not on Atlas, setting useUnifiedTopology to true caused my issues.  Removing this from my options made it work.

`{ useUnifiedTopology: false }` or don't set it at all and let it default to false

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8180

Answer (score 0):

**You are probably behind a corporate firewall.**

If you are not sure, you can check to see if you can reach the MongoDB port(27017 from your stacktrace) using a [third party site](http://portquiz.net:27017/), found in the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#attempting-to-connect-to-a-cluster-from-behind-a-firewall), where there are instructions specifically for the issue you've run into.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I restarted my computer and then suddenly my app wasn't working... so restarting mongoDB worked by running the following in my terminal (while in my api/mongoDB folder).

```
brew services stop mongodb-community@5.0
```

and then run

```
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `authSource=admin`, It works

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used `127.0.0.1:27017` instead of `localhost` and it worked